# How to run Sqlite CLI dot-commands (not SQL) using a C#.NET API or Nuget package

Tags: .net, sqlite, .net-core, standard-library

I'm looking for an API — ideally compatible with the .NET Standard Library, otherwise .NET Core or else .NET Framework (in that order) — that can be used to issue SQLite CLI [dot-commands](https://sqlite.org/cli.html) like .save .backup .databases .tables etc from my C# program to manage the database with and extract metadata from it.

There are an awful lot of nuget based SQLite packages available and I haven't found one that allows CLI commands, or I haven't figured out how to issue a CLI command properly through one. Most of these packages seem to deal with the SQL language rather than the SQLite engine.

Lastly I'm willing to use some other funky way to achieve this if no handy API is available.

Comment: If you're not using the sqlite3 command line shell and want the same functionality as a dot command you have to write it yourself. Sometimes it's easy (if, say, you want to implement `.backup` you can use the [backup API](https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) if it's provided by your languages sqlite bindings).